# How to assign the ADB command output to Robotframework variable and compare two values

Tags: robotframework

I am pretty new to the Robotframework and stuck with an issue where I am trying to fetch the device id from running this ADB command:

```
adb devices | grep -o '\b[a-f0-9]\+\b'
```

I am using the Run Process from Process Library to assign the device id that the ADB command returns to the RF variable called actual:

```
*** Variables ***
#WIN PORT BELOW
#${SERIAL_PORT}    COM3
#MAC path below
${SERIAL_ID}      178c5226

*** Test Cases ***
Test Device Serial Number
    [Documentation]  Run the adb shell and get device id/serial num and compare
    [Tags]  Smoke
    ${actual} =  Run Process  adb devices | grep -o '\b[a-f0-9]\+\b'  shell=True
    Should Be Equal     ${actual}    ${SERIAL_ID}
```

The actual variable is returning this:

```
<result object with rc 0>
```

Where the same command on my terminal returns the actual device id:

```
adb devices | grep -o '\b[a-f0-9]\+\b'         at 09:12:49 PM
178c5226
```

What I tried is adding the stdout at the end of the ${actual} variable and it returns an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a stdout in ${actual} but the **Run Process** keywords returns a result object. Have a look at the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object) about the result object.

```
Should Be Equal     ${actual.stdout}    ${SERIAL_ID}
```

Use this in your evaluation and you should get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but actual.stdout is still returning <result object with rc 0.> Any idea why?

Comment: I think that is correct in the log you should see that, what do you mean by return? What happens when you try to log the actual.stdout. 
Like so "Log    ${actual.stdout}", but do not change the line where you assign the value to variable "${actual}=    Run Process ..."